# How to get the right context

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I managed, with a lot of help from answers here, to add photo's taken with the tablet to a linearlayout by creating imageviews for them.
The pageviewer is loaded with a lot of copies of the same layout like the layout is custom control. Each layout has a button to take a photo and add it (or it should) to its own linearlayout.

But....

After a photo has been taken it is placed into the linearview, but it is not in the right page.

With this code it is placed in the linearlayout:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "photo_" + String.valueOf(requestCode) + ".png";
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        // bitmap still null
    } else {

        byte[] imageData = null;

        try {

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

            Float width = new Float(mBitmap.getWidth());
            Float height = new Float(mBitmap.getHeight());
            Float ratio = width / height;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, (int) (THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            imageData = baos.toByteArray();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }


        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        iv.setLayoutParams(params);
        iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        iv.setTag(_path);


        LinearLayout lvp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lvPhotos);
        lvp.addView(iv);

    }

}
```

Obviously I should not use **this** for the created imageview, but how do I get the context of the page on which the button for the camera was clicked?

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is here:

```
LinearLayout lvp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lvPhotos);
```

you find linearlayout which is placed on current content view. You need to find it on which linear should it be...

```
LinearLayout lvp = (LinearLayout) someView.findViewById(R.id.lvPhotos);
```

but i'm guessing that it's not a really good solution. You may want to set an array to keep your views instance so you can find them much more easily...

Comment: So with an global array and then an extra on the intent, I should be able to get the right view? Sounds like a plan. Thanks